# function Synchronization in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I have 5 different ajax requests in  different js code parts and only one handler:

```
ajaxRequest1
ajaxRequest2
ajaxRequest3
ajaxRequest4
ajaxRequest5
handler
```

I want to achieve following order:

If I invoke ajaxRequest1 I should handle it and only after it I can sen next ajaxRequest.

for example it is good ordering:

```
start ajaxRequest1
start handler
start ajaxRequest2
start handler
start ajaxRequest3
start handler
start ajaxRequest4
start handler
start ajaxRequest5
start handler
```

but it is bad:

```
start ajaxRequest1
start ajaxRequest2
start ajaxRequest3
start handler
start handler
start ajaxRequest4
start handler
start handler     
start ajaxRequest5
start handler
```

Does javascript allow to achieve it?

Comment: Yes it does. You simply start the next Ajax call from the handler (or whatever calls the handler). This has been asked before. Search for `serial ajax requests` or something similar.

Comment: yes it's possible with callback function

Comment: A lot of ways : Using callbacks as said ontop and nest the calls. Use promises and call next one in promise return. If you want to keep it clean and your open for a thirdparty library use https://github.com/caolan/async it will help you a lot also in more advanced situation as this.

Comment: @Felix Kling I cannot change location of ajax requests

Comment: Voting to close as unclear based on additional comments.

Comment: @Mathletics Do you try program on java?

Comment: @gstackoverflow what does java have to do with anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to wait for some condition to become true, before running something. If so, this can be accomplished with a `setTimeout` loop.

```
   function waitFor(fnReady, fnCallback) {
    var check = function() {
        if (fnReady()) {
            fnCallback();
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(check, 100);  // wait another 100ms, and try again
        }
    };

    check();
}


var result = 0;

function ajaxRequest1() {
    $.ajax(...).done(
         function() { result++; }
    );
}

function ajaxRequest2() {
    $.ajax(...).done(
         function() { result++; }
    );
}

waitFor(function() { return result === 1; }, ajaxRequest2);
waitFor(function() { return result === 2; }, ajaxRequest3);
```

Comment: can you provide demo on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: fnCheck is not defined

Comment: Fixed typo. `fnCheck` should have been just `check`.

Comment: It's because the `getJSON` method returns a `jqXHR` object, not a `Promise`. Pass your callback as a parameter to getJSON, instead of using `.done()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for Deferreds. If you are using jQuery, something like this should do what you want:

```
function ajaxRequest1() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax(...)
        .done(function(response) {
            if (/*response is valid*/)
                dfd.resolve(response);
            else
                dfd.reject();
        });
        .fail(function() {
            dfd.reject();
        });

    return dfd.promise();
}

function ajaxRequest2(response1) {
    // similar to ajaxRequest1, but with different URL, params
}

function ajaxRequest3(response2) {
   // similar to ajaxRequest2, but with different URL, params
}

// Run the tasks sequentially
$.when(ajaxRequest1())
    .then(ajaxRequest2)
    .then(ajaxRequest3)
    .done(function(result1, result2, result3) {
        // all requests have completed
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // handle error
    });
```

Here, each ajaxRequestX function is also the handler. It checks the response received from the previous request, and if everything is okay, it kicks off the next request. Check out jQuery's Deferred object for more info.

Comment: Deferreds is how jQuery implements it. The overall concept is called Promises: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: no no no. I have rad about deffered a munute ago. It allow to execute function after another function termination. I want to freeze func1 execution while func2 is not terminated

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? JavaScript is single-threaded, so only one function is running at any one time.

Comment: jQuery `$.ajax` already returns a promise; you don't need wrap it in a second one. You can just do `$.when($.ajax(whatever)).then(...)`.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: do you mean that you want to send an AJAX request, and not have any more code execute until you receive the response from the request? You can do that by making your request synchronous, instead of asynchronous. For example, if you’re using [the `XMLHTTPRequest` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), you set the `async` argument of the `open` method to `false`.

Comment: @alekop you can understand freeze something like Thread.yeld in java

Comment: @Mathletics: Yes, but then you'd lose the ability to validate the response, before triggering the next request. (/* response is valid */ comment)

Comment: **What do you mean by freeze? JavaScript is single-threaded, so only one function is running at any one time** I want that any another function executes while condition is become true

Comment: What? No; your server should return an error if the response is invalid. Are you expecting a `200 OK` with garbage data? And even still, you are actually _using the promise interface to do that check_! So you can test the response in the next handler before you fire off the subsequent call. You just have a lot of extra code for nothing.

Comment: @Mathletics: Not exactly garbage, but a response indicating the result of the request. Maybe an error code/message, etc.

Comment: An error from the server will result in the `$.ajax` promise being rejected. If your server responds with a `200` plus an error message, you screwed up your server design.

Comment: I have ajaxRequest1 - [0-10] time. ajaxRequest2 - [2-4] time hence ajaxRequest1 will get and handle after ajaxRequest2. For my application it is wrong

Comment: @gstackoverflow: If you want to defer the execution of the next request until some condition becomes true, you can use `setTimeout`.

Comment: timeout works after concrete time interval. I want to write custom condition

Comment: @Mathletics: Sometimes an 200 OK response is not really valid; Man-in-the-middle attacks, for example. Just some extra error checking. Yes, you can omit the inner Deferred, if you really want.